# Drawing text and line-dasharray

Tags: tilemill, map-drawing, cartocss, text

Is it possible with TileMills and CartoCSS?

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to provide more details about what you are asking, please?  Normally about a paragraph is considered "minimum length" for Questions and Answers.  I **think** you may be asking whether the line symbols you illustrated can be used, but do the letters correspond to different layers, different field values in the same layer, or ...?

Comment: Updated image, i hope my question is more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. This rendering is common for contour lines. See [this blog entry](http://wygoda.net/blog/better-contours-tilemill) for CartoCSS code.

I should warn you that when using this code (specifically, `text-comp-op` operation), you won't be able to export your map in a vector format: SVG and PDF output would produce a raster image in a vector container. You might not need it though.

Comment: Yes! Thx for this and for штосм ;)